# Which bus goes to the city? VS which bus does go to the city?

Tags: grammaticality

I have a question

Which bus goes to the city? VS which bus does go to the city?

Which one is correct? I'm so confused

Comment: They are both correct.  It depends on the context. The first is used when trying to find the right bus. The second after being told that the one you thought went there, doesn’t.

Answer (score 2):

"Which bus goes to the city?" is the correct one in the normal context. But for an emphatic purpose or insisting on an answer, "Tell me, which bus does go to the city?" is also possible.
If the question words (*What, Which, Who, Whose, How many* etc) come as the subject or subject part of the question, normally forms of ***do*** (*do, does, did*) are not used.  But forms of *do* can be used for emphasis after the subject question words.
[image: A screen shot from the Practical English Usage is here:]

Answer (score 1):

Your first sentence is correct and is preferable

> Which bus goes to the city?

In your second sentence *does* is not necessary and is redundant since "*does go*" = "*go*", though one might use "does" for emphasis, though it is not necessary

> Which bus does go to the city?

However, *does* is necessary for the negative

> Which bus *does not* go to the city?

Comment: Also when asking about a specific bus you would say:
"Does this bus go to the city?"

Comment: @Nathan That's exactly what one would ask "Does this bus go to *someplace*?"